# sort files twice

Tags: shell-script, sort

I have a series of 300+ files that I need to sort twice, once by the date and a second time within that date by part of the filename.
The only standard in the names is that ends with `*mmddyyyy<time stamp>.csv`, where the first part of the file name can include anything at all.  I know `ls -ltr` gives me the date sort but I can't seem to capture and sort on a portion of the last keydef.

Comment: They even have spaces in the file names... :(

Comment: Although names can vary, can you still post three full file names, so don't do `<time stamp>` do the actual time stamp for example. That way it makes it possible to see if there is some pattern that can be usable for sorting.

Comment: Maybe a sample input and expected output could help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: These guys were real buggers... the front part of the filename is literally anything at all - whatever a human typed in.  Some of the problem children were names like - "180195-49 (2).hdl.02042015021509.csv" or "15-1 15-2.hdl.03302015064508.csv" but more "normalized" names were "2-17-15.hdl.02172015085537.csv"  as examples.

Answer (score 0):

Given that when looking at the filenames from the end side they have a predictable format (extension then time then date) one can leverage this fact and use the following command:

```
ls -1 | rev | sort -t '~' -k1.14,1.14 -k1.13,1.13 -k1.12,1.12 -k1.11,1.11 -k1.18,1.18 -k1.17,1.17 -k1.16,1.16 -k1.15,1.15 | rev
```

Explanation:
- the filenames are first reversed so we can access the desired format
- the result is then sorted character by character, depending on our needs:
- - the characters 11 to 14 are the year (in reverse order)
- - the characters 17 to 18 are the month (in reverse order)
- - the characters 15 to 16 are the day (in reverse order)
- finally another reversal takes place to display them with original names

I've used the tilde `~` as separator in order to combine the whole filename in one field but you can play around using a different one (it has to be a character never present in the filenames) or just use a `.` (dot) in order to split the filename in several fields (if their amount is always the same) so that you can specify other parts to be sorted upon - for your second question.